# Sum of Squares of Floor Function

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Similar to how the divisor summatory function, $D(x)$, is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^x \lfloor \frac xn \rfloor$, is there a similar function for $\sum_{n=1}^x \lfloor \frac xn \rfloor^2$?

Comment: The full answers is at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94827/the-second-moment-of-a-sum-of-floor-functions

Comment: The full answer is at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94827/the-second-moment-of-a-sum-of-floor-functions plus a generalization to any power k.